# Move child folder contents to parent folder in python

Tags: python

I have a specific problem in python. Below is my folder structure.

`dstfolder/slave1/slave`

I want the contents of `'slave'` folder to be moved to `'slave1'` (parent folder). Once moved,
`'slave'` folder should be deleted. `shutil.move` seems to be not helping.

Please let me know how to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried? `shutil.move(src,dst)` documentation says "Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst)", so it should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example using the os and shutil modules:

```
from os.path import join
from os import listdir, rmdir
from shutil import move

root = 'dstfolder/slave1'
for filename in listdir(join(root, 'slave')):
    move(join(root, 'slave', filename), join(root, filename))
rmdir(join(root, 'slave'))
```

Comment: Thanks tito, minor changes and it worked !!! Sorry can't voteup as my reputation is very low :-(

Comment: Also you can move parent folder content to a new child folder using,
Let say you need to move dir1/* to dir1/dir2. So you can do,
`shutil.move("dir1", "dir2)`
`shutil.move("dir2", oa.path.join("dir1", "dir2")`

Comment: last line should be `rmdir(join(root, 'slave'))`

Answer (score 3):

I needed something a little more generic, i.e. move all the files from all the [sub]+folders into the root folder.

For example start with:

```
root_folder
|----test1.txt
|----1
     |----test2.txt
     |----2
          |----test3.txt
```

And end up with:

```
root_folder
|----test1.txt
|----test2.txt
|----test3.txt
```

A quick recursive function does the trick:

```
import os, shutil, sys 

def move_to_root_folder(root_path, cur_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(cur_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cur_path, filename)):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(cur_path, filename), os.path.join(root_path, filename))
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(cur_path, filename)):
            move_to_root_folder(root_path, os.path.join(cur_path, filename))
        else:
            sys.exit("Should never reach here.")
    # remove empty folders
    if cur_path != root_path:
        os.rmdir(cur_path)
```

You will usually call it with the same argument for `root_path` and `cur_path`, e.g. `move_to_root_folder(os.getcwd(),os.getcwd())` if you want to try it in the python environment.

Comment: What if the files have the same names? Could you update it for this case, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the path you specified in the shutil.move function

Try this code

```
import os
import shutil
for r,d,f in os.walk("slave1"):
    for files in f:
        filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"slave1","slave", files)
        destpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"slave1")
        shutil.copy(filepath,destpath)

shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"slave1","slave"))
```

Paste it into a .py file in the dstfolder. I.e. slave1 and this file should remain side by side. and then run it. worked for me

Comment: Also check whether you have the required permissions as well

Answer (score 0):

Use this if the files have same names, new file names will have folder names joined by '_'

```py
import shutil
import os

source = 'path to folder'

def recursive_copy(path):

    for f in sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))):

        file = os.path.join(path, f)

        if os.path.isfile(file):

            temp = os.path.split(path)
            f_name = '_'.join(temp)
            file_name = f_name + '_' + f
            shutil.move(file, file_name)

        else:

            recursive_copy(file)
         
recursive_copy(source)
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you could get into the dictionary slave, and then

```
exec system('mv .........')
```

It will work won't it?

Comment: This answer is specific to POSIX operating systems and will cause code to be less portable.