# read csv file to rename and move to new (variable) path

Tags: path, move, subdirectory, file-rename, read-csv

I have hundreds of files in subdirectories that need to be renamed and then moved to a new location specified in a csv column (the path depends on the ID and reference ID). I need to rename the files in their original location first since some may have the same filename (e.g. new_reqest_11_02_01.pdf).

**Current structure + filename:**

A/new_reqest_11_02_01.pdf

B/new_reqest_11_02_01.pdf

B/new_reqest_11_03_01.pdf

**Desired Structure + filename:**

A/123456/A_F_11_02_01.pdf

B/123964/B_R_11_02_01.pdf

B/158964/B_G_11_02_01.pdf

The filename and path will be created using columns in the csv:

| Client | RequestID | OldFileName | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123456 | new_reqest_11_02_01.pdf | F | 11_02_01 |
| B | 123964 | new_reqest_11_03_01.pdf | R | 11_02_01 |

I can move all files and rename them, but that doesn't work because files with the same name are overwritten. I've tried creating the directory tree (successfully) from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816740/python-create-multiple-folders-by-reading-csv-file-and-also-check-if-folders-a), but the reference to csv columns to rename the file and create a new path stump me.

```
import os
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Testing\\Rename_Refile.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    header = next(readCSV)
    for row in readCSV:
        dirname = "/".join((row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)
```

I tried to mishmash misc. code across stackoverflow, but it's too disjointed and I haven't been able to find a question on changing a file path using csv column's.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting, I have the following code modified from a few different posts ([Source A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650850/how-to-rename-a-file-with-values-of-csv-file), [Source B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428954/move-child-folder-contents-to-parent-folder-in-python))

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\me\Desktop\\SA and M letters\\Rename_Refile.csv',delimiter=',')
Old_Directory = "C:\\Users\me\\Desktop\\SA and M letters\\OldDirectory\\"
New_Directory = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\SA and M letters\\NewDirectory\\"


sub_directories = df["sub_directories"]
Request_ID = df["Request_ID"]
OriginalFileName = df["OriginalFileName"]
NewFileName = df["NewFileName"]

for row in df:
    dirname = "/".join((Old_Directory,row[1], row[4]))
    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname)
            
            
for sub_dir in enumerate(sub_directories):
    old_path = os.path.join(Old_Directory, sub_dir)
    new_path = os.path.join(New_Directory, sub_directories,Request_ID)
    old_name = OriginalFileName
    new_name = NewFileName 
    try:
        os.rename(os.path.join(old_path, old_name), os.path.join(old_path, new_name))
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(old_path, new_name), os.path.join(new_path,new_name))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Rename for %s failed. Details: ' % old_name)
        print(e)
```

This creates the new directory tree, renames the files in their original location then copy the file to it's new path in the new directory tree created. I keep getting `TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'` though...